# JMeter how to refresh token csrf laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, jmeter

I have a jmeter test for laravel application, the question is why every page i get from http request sampler have a same csrf-token (_token)

this is my jmeter structure

[image]

first i want get token from home page for post in login page
[image]

after that I tried to log in using "post login" http request and succeed,

but when i want to get new token in "shopping cart page" why i get the same token like this :

[image]

so when i want to post a new http request with token, what i get is like this : 
[image]

can someone help me how to make the "shoppig cart page" generate a new token for post new htpp request ?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is not corresponding to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), if you place Regular Expression Extractors at the same level as [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers the Regular Expression Extractors will be applied to all HTTP Request samplers one-by-one.

Try moving the extractors **as children** of the HTTP Requests, this way their scope will be limited to the current sampler only and the variable value will not be overwritten by the subsequent executions.

[image]

Also be aware that [using Regular Expressions to parse HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), consider using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) instead.